# Pandas to_csv() disable float

Tags: csv, pandas

Pandas `to_csv()` is converting integers into floats. How can I disable this?

I have set `float_format=None` but same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.to_csv()` would not normally convert to `float`. Is there any chance that you have any `np.nan` in this column? If you do then the dtype for this column will be `float64`.

When an `np.nan` is introduced in an otherwise `int` or `bool` column, the entire column is casted to `float`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: You are right. What I thought to be `int` got recasted as `float64`. I used `astype(int)` to fix it.

Comment: One of those things!